# jQuery - Stick div to bottom of window when out of view

Tags: jquery, sticky

Been searching  a while for this, no real luck yet. and would kind of like to do it without a plugin.

I am trying to make it so a selected div (footer) would come into view when the page is being scrolled. I managed to find a way to do it for the navigation menu at the top of the window, but it just seems harder for the bottom part of the window..

Here's what I have used for the Top

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { // document ready
  var stickyTop = $('#Sticky').offset().top; // returns number  
  $(window).scroll( function(){ // scroll event
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number
    if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
      $('#Sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0});
    }
    else {
      $('#Sticky').css('position','static');
    }
  });
});
```

and it works great. Anyway to modify this and use it for the same (if not similar) effect at the bottom?

Also, sorry if I make little sense..

Comment: Why would you make your footer stick to the bottom when you scroll down? it's at the bottom then? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, its a part of the footer which will contain another menu.. will make things a bit easier for people navigating my site.

Comment: But that part is sticked to the bottom already right? Could you explain with a sketch or something?

Comment: The footer is usually the last thing on the page. Just make it always fixed and add a margin to the main content container that is as big as the footer. That will create a whitespace at the bottom that will be filled with the footer when the page is completely scrolled down. Otherwise just use `scrollTop()`, `offset().top` and `.height()` to find out if the element is completely in view.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Bc0FFa9.png
So when the footer menu is out of view, it gets 'fixed' to the bottom of the window.

Comment: Why dont you just do the exacte opposite of the code you have here??

Comment: Can you not just set the `position` to `fixed` + `bottom:0px;` since it is always at the bottom anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var stickyBottom = $('#stickyBottom').height();
  $('#stickyBottom').css({'position':'fixed','bottom':stickyBottom});

  $(window).scroll(function()
    $('#stickyBottom').css('bottom','0');
  });
});
```

Comment: Getting an error with
  var stickyBottom = $('#stickyBottom').height();

Comment: Seems to find a problem with    $('#stickyBottom').css('bottom','0');